# json - how to get data from json where user's input will come on %s

Tags: php, mysql, json

I've got a JSON file which looks like this

```
{
  "facebook": {
    "icon": "fab fa-facebook",
    "title": "Facebook",
    "url": "https://facebook.com/%s"
  },
  "instagram": {
    "icon": "fab fa-instagram",
    "title": "Instagram",
    "url": "https://instagram.com/%s"
  }
}
```

So I'm getting users social links from a form, but only the user's ID of social link eg.`https://facebook.com/ID`. I'm storing the users ID in JSON file in database. I'm using PHP. How do I add the users ID in that `'%s'` and display the link.

Comment: Use sprintf for that. The userId will be replaced with the '%s' `sprintf($data->facebook['url'], $userId);`

Comment: I get it, but how do I display it in 'a' tag. I'll get the links from json file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put together the information using the JSON data you have, you would use either [`sprintf()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) or [`printf()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) (the only difference being the `printf()` directly outputs the data `sprintf()` returns a string).  The information on the manual pages shows how things like `%s` works.

So the code would look something like...

```
$id = 123;
$userName = "User name";

$json = '{
    "facebook": {
    "icon": "fab fa-facebook",
    "title": "Facebook",
    "url": "https://facebook.com/%s"
    },
    "instagram": {
    "icon": "fab fa-instagram",
    "title": "Instagram",
    "url": "https://instagram.com/%s"
    }
}';

$socialMedia = json_decode( $json, true );

echo echo '<a href="'.sprintf($socialMedia["facebook"]["url"], $id).'">'.
   $userName.'</a>';
```

Which outputs...

```
<a href="https://facebook.com/123">User name</a>
```